# Heroku failed to connect to MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I setup a free MongoDB Atlas cluster, and it gave me the following URI. I can connect to it with mongo shell in Mac.

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.hmd0i.mongodb.net
```

But when deployed with [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), it raised the error in the logs.

```
2020-12-27T13:31:11.086770+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-12-27T13:31:11.086684 #4]  INFO -- : [1debe7b7-24d9-4958-ac5b-c72a34d03290] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2020-12-27T13:31:11.087354+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-12-27T13:31:11.087286 #4] FATAL -- : [1debe7b7-24d9-4958-ac5b-c72a34d03290]   
2020-12-27T13:31:11.087411+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-12-27T13:31:11.087353 #4] FATAL -- : [1debe7b7-24d9-4958-ac5b-c72a34d03290] Mongo::Error::InvalidURI (Bad URI: mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.hmd0i.mongodb.net/
2020-12-27T13:31:11.087412+00:00 app[web.1]: Invalid scheme. Scheme must be 'mongodb://'
2020-12-27T13:31:11.087413+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoDB URI must be in the following format: mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

It constantly complaining `Scheme must be 'mongodb://'`. But what I got is `mongodb+srv://`.

How to fix it? Or anything I missed? Thanks!

-----Edited-----

I'm using [Mongoid](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/) 6.0.2. And the `mongoid.yml` is as following.

```yaml
production:
  clients:
    default:
     uri: <%= ENV['MONGO_URI'] %>
```

I tried with a very simple code, it works in local.

```
require 'mongoid'

Mongoid.load!("mongoid.yml", :production)

class Ticket
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :opened_at, type: DateTime
end

ticket = Ticket.create!(opened_at: '2020-02-18 07:00:08 -0500')
puts ticket.opened_at
```

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @BeppeC. I'm using mongoid. So the error comes from mongoid?

Comment: I would think so, the connection string seems fine (it is the same using Python), you might be able to get a different connection string in Atlas depending on Ruby driver version

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link on how i connected my own website to heroku Atlas
https://dev.to/cpclark360/how-to-host-a-restful-node-js-server-with-mongodb-atlas-database-on-heroku-1opl

And if you have an .env file you should use

```
DB_CONNECT = mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.hmd0i.mongodb.net
```